# Convolve each layer in a stack of matrices using numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, convolution

Suppose that I have a stack of matrices `A` of shape `N*H*W` and a filter `B` of shape `h*w`. I would like to compute the following:

```py
C = np.stack([
    scipy.signal.convolve(
        A[i, :, :],
        B,
        mode='same'
    )
    for i in range(N)
], axis=0)
```

What is the fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is vectorized code:

```py
C = scipy.signal.convolve(
    A,
    B[np.newaxis, ...],
    mode='same'
)
```

However, it is surprizingly slower than `np.stack` for `N` from 10 to 10000 and `(H, W) = (84, 84)`, `(h, w) = (13, 13)` (these are the values I was interested in for my particular problem).

[image: comparison of stacked and vectorized]

Benchmarking code (to be run in IPython):

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

H, W = 84, 84
h, w = 13, 13

def benchmark(N):
    A = np.random.normal(size=(N, H, W))
    B = np.random.normal(size=(h, w))

    t1 = %timeit -qo np.stack([scipy.signal.convolve(A[i, :, :], B, mode='same') for i in range(N)])
    t2 = %timeit -qo scipy.signal.convolve(A, B[np.newaxis, ...], mode='same')

    return t1.timings, t2.timings

Ns = (10**np.linspace(1, 4, 16)).round().astype(int)

results = [benchmark(N) for N in Ns]

ns = []
timings = []
run_type = []

for N, (t1_timings, t2_timings) in zip(Ns, results):
    cnt = len(t1_timings)
    ns.extend([N] * cnt)
    timings.extend(t1_timings)
    run_type.extend(['stack'] * cnt)

    cnt = len(t2_timings)
    ns.extend([N] * cnt)
    timings.extend(t2_timings)
    run_type.extend(['vectorized'] * cnt)

df = pd.DataFrame({'N': ns, 'timings': timings, 'type': run_type})
sns.lineplot(x='N', y='timings', hue='type', data=df)
```